# Bootstrap Carousel does not load until first interval has expired

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Carousel and have a set of images that only load as fast as I set the "interval" parameter. So, if I sat `{interval:10}`, then everything loads in a jiffy, but if I set `{interval:6000}`, I have to wait for 6 seconds.

There is [an issue on github](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4420) where the bootstrap carousel wouldn't load until the first image has loaded and adding ".active" to the first div seemed to have fixed the issue. However, that solution doesn't work for me. I added the active class and yet, the div.active doesn't actually render until the interval has elapsed.

Question - have you seen similar behavior and do you know how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do your images have a particularly large file size?

Comment: No, not particularly. Also, on short intervals images load fast, so I don't see why file size would impact them loading slower on larger intervals.

Comment: What version of bootstrap-carousel do you have? there's been a few recent changes in the repro recently may change behavior around the interval option. (e.g. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/a866a51a2ecac07748501f0375a324ebb57002f2)

Comment: I am on v2.2.1. I could try upgrading to the latest and see if that fixes the issue. Will get back to you on that one!

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000
    });

    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
});
```

Comment: Worked great. The only thing I'd add here, is add "active" to the class of the item *before* the one you want to show first since "next" will move to that one.